# wkhtmltopdf page margin from second page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

**First page**

In my pdf the header on the first page should have no offset. So the margin from the top is zero.

**Second and following pages**

I want to set a top margin for the second page and the following pages.

**Question**

How do I do this?
If I set a margin via args from the command line call of `wkhtmltopdf` every page including the first one gets the margin I've set.

[image]

This is the output at the second page which should need to have some top margin.

Comment: What did you try so far in terms of HTM/CSS code?

Comment: I try to set a header on every page. The result is that the page heading via html/css overlaps the content on the second page and not pushing it down.

Comment: I mean could you provide a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

WK only supports setting the header/footer globally - not on a per page/input basis.

Will your first page content ever need to flow onto the second page, or can it be rendered separately?  If the latter, then I would suggest creating two different PDFs with WK, one for the first page, and one for the remaining pages.  Then join the two up using a merger (e.g. https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger).  That way, you can set different margins on each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line arguments -T 30 -B 20 -L 10 -R 10 to set default margins for all ap